# In R: putting similar files in a folder with the same prefix

Tags: r

I have a folder with files that have been created for a subset of populations. Each population has 3 different files created containing data, each file starting with XXX_ to denote the population and then after the "_" the file type is indicated (all followed by .txt).
For example:
AAA_dat1.txt 
AAA_dat2.txt
AAA_dat3.txt
BBB_dat1.txt
BBB_dat2.txt
BBB_dat3.txt

I have successively created new folders for each of the populations pulled from my dataset (so for this example I have folders AAA and BBB). I now wish to move only AAA_dat1.txt and AAA_dat2.txt to folder AAA and BBB_dat1.txt and BBB_dat2.txt to folder BBB, leaving both AAA_dat3.txt and BBB_dat3.txt in the current folder. Since I will have datasets with varying population numbers I am looking for a way to not have to manually move the files for each population each time. Is there such as way to do this?

This is how I was able to create the new folders I wish to move the files into:

```
newfolders <- c(pops) #pops is the list of populations directly from the dataset

for (j in 1:length(newfolders)){
folder<-dir.create(paste0("~/pathhere/",newfolders[j]))
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Finding the directory is easy enough, something like `gsub("_.*","\\1","AAA_dat1.txt")` will get that ... but how do you know that `dat2` should move but `dat3` does not ... is it *always* "3" that does not move?

Comment: The 3 files that are created will alway have the population code followed by dat1, dat2, or dat3. Dat 1 and dat2 will always move to the new folder, and dat3 will always remain in the folder it was created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a shot:

```r
filenames <- c(
  "AAA_dat1.txt", "AAA_dat2.txt", "AAA_dat3.txt",
  "BBB_dat1.txt", "BBB_dat2.txt", "BBB_dat3.txt"
)

dirs <- gsub("_.*", "", basename(filenames))
dirs
# [1] "AAA" "AAA" "AAA" "BBB" "BBB" "BBB"
```

While not strictly necessary to produce a `data.frame` for this, it makes things a little easier to index and see things:

```r
moves <- data.frame(
  origpath = filenames, # not basename'd
  newpath = file.path(dirs, basename(filenames))
)[ !grepl("dat3", basename(filenames)), ]
moves
#       origpath          newpath
# 1 AAA_dat1.txt AAA/AAA_dat1.txt
# 2 AAA_dat2.txt AAA/AAA_dat2.txt
# 4 BBB_dat1.txt BBB/BBB_dat1.txt
# 5 BBB_dat2.txt BBB/BBB_dat2.txt
```

Notice that the `dat3` files aren't in there. The purpose of this frame is to rename (move) files, and since we aren't moving them, we don't need to do *anything* to them in this context.

We can move them all in one fell swoop:

```r
file.rename(moves$origpath, moves$newpath)
```

---

BTW: the use of `basename` above was to handle the situation where either (1) the original files are not in the current directory, or (2) you used `list.files(..., full.names=TRUE)` (such that the full path might be included). It works just fine when they are all in the current dir or if otherwise, such as

```r
filenames <- c(
  "path1/AAA_dat1.txt", "path1/AAA_dat2.txt", "path99/AAA_dat3.txt",
  "path2/BBB_dat1.txt", "path1/BBB_dat2.txt", "somepath/BBB_dat3.txt"
)
dirs  # derived as above
# [1] "AAA" "AAA" "AAA" "BBB" "BBB" "BBB"
moves # derived as above
#             origpath          newpath
# 1 path1/AAA_dat1.txt AAA/AAA_dat1.txt
# 2 path1/AAA_dat2.txt AAA/AAA_dat2.txt
# 4 path2/BBB_dat1.txt BBB/BBB_dat1.txt
# 5 path1/BBB_dat2.txt BBB/BBB_dat2.txt
```